# Understanding students t-test

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, mean

Suppose we have 4 groups of sample data with equal sizes and we want compare mean of group 1 with group 2 and group 3 with group 4. So we perform independent sample t-test on the pair of groups and their results are as follows

**group 1, group 2**

```
t_score = -5000, p_value = 0
mean(group 1) < mean(group 2)
```

**group 3, group 4**

```
t_score = -100, p_value = 0
mean(group 3) < mean(group 4)
```

What conclusion we can draw from this data. I am new to statistics, if the question seems very general then please forgive me.

Comment: It seems that your grouping variable (`group`) has four levels - namely `group 1`,  `group 2`,  `group 3`  and `group 4`. Is that so?

Comment: @AyalewA. I don't need to compare all 4 groups only pair wise analysis is needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have correctly coded the problem, you can conclude that there are statistically significant differences between a) Group 1 and 2 and b) Group 3 and 4 and that groups 2 and 4 have higher means than groups 1 and 3, respectively.

However, I am a bit worried that things were done correctly.

The output is very minimal.  A p value can never be 0, so there was some sort of rounding done there. And a t score of -5000 is very, very big. This is the sort of t you would get if you compared the heights of basketball players and jockeys.

Also, the t scores were rounded to integers, which is odd.

Comment: I think if `group` is a variable with four levels, it seems better to go for `one-way ANOVA`. Subsequent to the `one-way ANOVA`, pair-wise comparison could be considered with adjustment for multiple testing.

Comment: @Ayalew, I disagree because the OP explicitly states that he wants to compare group 1 to 2 and 3 to 4, so there is no benefit of testing additional hypotheses.

Comment: @FransRodenburg yes you are right I just need to compare g1 with g2 and g3 with g4

Comment: @PeterFlom yes there is rounding p value were very small

Comment: It is peculiar to have rounded t statics that are 5000 and 100.